# android - removing list view items before rebuilding list view

Tags: android, list, listview

I have a list view, when I go back and come back to my list activity the list is duplicated. The first list needs to be removed so only one list is displayed. Any ideas???

This is my List Activity code:

```
package com.sportspubfinder;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListPubsActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog ShowProgress;

    ListView lv1;

    int selectedRadius;

    Double userLat;
    Double userLong;


    public static ArrayList<SetterGetter> PubList = new ArrayList<SetterGetter>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pubslist);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            //retrieve the passed through radius and location readings 
            selectedRadius = extras.getInt("radius_set");
            userLat = extras.getDouble("latitude_set");
            userLong = extras.getDouble("longitude_set");
        }

         //show progres bar whilst a connection is made with the url
        ShowProgress = ProgressDialog.show(ListPubsActivity.this, "",
                "Loading Pubs. Please wait...", true);

        /* --If the INAPUB api was implemented, the url would take the passed radius (selectRadius) and location of the user---
          * "http://api.inapub.co.uk/venues/geocode/"+userLat+"/"+userLong+"/"+selectedRadius+"/?API_Key=7xa3tdmjkhu6jwjvp746zgg4");*/ 
        new loadingTask().execute("http://itsuite.it.brighton.ac.uk/jp232/pubs.php");

        //check which list item has been selected
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ListPubsActivity.this, PubActivity.class);
                //pass the pubs information through to the next activity
                intent.putExtra("pubName", PubList.get(position).getName()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubImage", PubList.get(position).getThumbnail()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubAddress", PubList.get(position).getAddress()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubTown", PubList.get(position).getTown()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubCounty", PubList.get(position).getCounty()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubDescription", PubList.get(position).getDescription()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubFacilities", PubList.get(position).getFacilities()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubRating", PubList.get(position).getRating()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubLatitude", PubList.get(position).getLatitude()); 
                intent.putExtra("pubLongitude", PubList.get(position).getLongitude());

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    class loadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        //check if there's an Internet connection
        /*public boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
               cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }*/

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //in background wait to receive the information from the ListHandler
            SAXHelper sh = null;
            try {
                sh = new SAXHelper(urls[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sh.parseContent("");
            return "";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //add Custom List Adapter once ListHandler has been received 
            lv1.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(ListPubsActivity.this, PubList));
            //stop progress bar
            ShowProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }

    class SAXHelper {

        public HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private URL url2;

        public SAXHelper(String url1) throws MalformedURLException {
            this.url2 = new URL(url1);
        }

        public ListHandler parseContent(String parseContent) {
            //add the ListHandler
            ListHandler df = new ListHandler();
            try {

                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                xr.setContentHandler(df);
                xr.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return df;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
       super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide the code where PubList is getting populated .........

Comment: In `onItemClick()` you might want to add a variable link this: `GetterSetter current = PubList.get(position);`. This will save you repeated look-ups to the same List item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static ArrayList PubList = new ArrayList();
```

I believe, due to the static type, your list contents are getting appended.

Comment: Is there another way round this than deleting the static type?

Comment: You could try clearing the list in the onCreate method. That would make sure that the list is empty when you open the activity.

Comment: I have been trying to achieve this with no prevail. What is the code you use for clearing a list? thank you for your help so far